# Knitr with LaTeX - Background color with option result='asis'

Tags: r, colors, background, latex, knitr

When I compile a LaTeX document containing a chunk of knitr code, I can change the background color with option result='markup'

```
<<results='markup', background='#FFFFDD'>>=
1+1
@
```

But I can't do the same if the option is result='asis'

```
<<results='asis', background='#FFFFDD'>>=
1+1
@
```

Is there a solution to change the background color when the results option is 'asis'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

knitr won't do custom background colors for asis because the background color is set for the whole block with the R code AND the output under 'markup' and there is no such block when you're writing results 'asis'. However, there is a workaround if you want the R code to be formatted with a custom background: Make your own block (with \begingroup and \endgroup), and override the value for shadecolor in that block:

```
\begingroup
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1, 1, 0.867}
<<results='asis'>>=
2+2
@
\endgroup
```